# Wildcards in GRANT statement?

Tags: sql, mysql

The following does work as expected:

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* to 'someuser'@'%' identified by 'somepass';
```

Can I use wildcards for Database name like:

```
GRANT ALL ON someDB*.* to 'someuser'@'%' identified by 'somepass';
```

Comment: Less than 25% acceptance on ~30 questions?

Answer (score 3):

From [MySQL 5.1 documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html):

> The "_" and "%" wildcards are allowed
>   when specifying database names in
>   GRANT statements that grant privileges
>   at the global or database levels. This
>   means, for example, that if you want
>   to use a "_" character as part of a
>   database name, you should specify it
>   as "\_" in the GRANT statement, to
>   prevent the user from being able to
>   access additional databases matching
>   the wildcard pattern; for example,
>   GRANT ... ON 'foo\_bar'.* TO ....

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code:

```
GRANT ALL ON `someDB_%`.* TO 'someuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'somepass';
```

You have to use "`" as character to specify wildcard on database name.